# ブログプラットフォームGhost のテーマで現在のページの種類に応じて処理を分岐する方法

Tags: html

Ghost のテンプレートエンジンとして採用されている handlebars で
ページの種類によって分岐するコードを実装したいと考えいています.

Ghost 自体を拡張して文字列比較をするブロックヘルパーを追加すれば
簡単にできるのはわかっているのですがテーマで完結する方法を探しています.

{{body_class}} でそれっぽい変数は取れるのですが,
文字列比較をするブロックヘルパーがないみたいでして...

下記のような形で実装できたらと考えています.

```
{{#if page_type "home"}}
<h1>ホームだよー</h1>
{{/if}}
{{#if page_type "post"}}
<h1>ポストだよー</h1>
{{/if}}
{{#if page_type "tag"}}
<h1>タグだよー</h1>
{{/if}}
```

Ghost については日本語の情報がかなり少ないので
些細なことでもコメント頂けると幸いです.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ghost自体を使ってないんで、見当違いの情報かもしれませんがGithubのソースを見てみると、
以下のようにisヘルパーがあるようです。

https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/master/core/server/helpers/is.js

上記のisヘルパーのソースコードの「Usage:」の内容や、
以下のisヘルパーのテスト用コードの字面の感じから、

https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/master/core/test/unit/server_helpers/is_spec.js

isヘルパーを利用すれば、現在の表示中のページが
どこのページなのかという判定をかけれるのではないでしょうか

Comment: まさにー！！
これでいけました(^-^)
てかワテさんだ笑
ありがとうござます。

Comment: ちなみにこんな感じでいけました.

    {{#is "home"}}
    <h1>ホームだよー</h1>
    {{/is}}

Comment: ファイさんが質問してたので、気になってGithubのGhostのソースを感覚で洗ってたら、
それっぽいのが見つかったんで、少しでも参考になればってことで一応、レスしたんですけど、
参考になってよかったです！ｗ